# ValueError: new_order[2] is 1, but the input only has 1 axes

Tags: theano

For the following piece of code:

```
imgs = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(numpy.random.uniform((batch_size,c,n1,n2)),dtype=theano.config.floatX))
imgs = imgs.dimshuffle((0,'x', 1, 2, 3))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: new_order[2] is 1, but the input only has 1 axes.
```

I do not see where the problem is exactly. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to tell what parameter is `(batch_size,c,n1,n2)`

```
imgs = theano.shared(numpy.asarray(numpy.random.uniform(size=(batch_size,c,n1,n2)),dtype=theano.config.floatX))
imgs = imgs.dimshuffle((0,'x', 1, 2, 3))
```